# Can I at least have a backup of my deleted question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, meta

Since this forum is witch hunting broad hardware recommendation questions (making this forum useless for apparently 99% of the users), and deleting the question without a single warning, can you at least make a backup of the topic I took ten minutes to write (and you took 5 seconds to delete), so I can post on a not dead forum ?

Answer (score 2):

You can still find the question via your browser history; authors can [always view their own posts even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/295232):

> #### Can I still see my own post even after it's deleted?
>
> You can see any of your own questions that you have the direct link to, and your own deleted answers to any question.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you. But the obvious question remains: when one doesn't have the link (my case).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you'd taken the time to read the help and topic guidelines before you posted, you might not have had such a frustrating experience.

Here's your question:

> [image]

Comment: Yeah... I really should... What was I thinking by asking for a hardware recommendation on a site called "Hardware recommendation", right ?